# Is this a valid implementation of `std::mem::drop`?

Tags: memory-management, rust, destructor

According to [*The Rust Programming Language*, ch15-03](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch15-03-drop.html), `std::mem::drop` takes an object, receives its ownership, and calls its `drop` function.

That's what this code does:

```
fn my_drop<T>(x: T) {}

fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    let y = &x;
    let mut z = 4;

    let v = vec![3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 5];

    my_drop(v);
}
```

Is this what `std::mem::drop` does? Does it perform any other cleanup tasks other than these?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's take a look at the [source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a7170b0412d1baa4e30cb31d1ea326617021f086/src/libcore/mem.rs#L785-L787):

```
#[inline]
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
pub fn drop<T>(_x: T) { }
```

`#[inline]` gives a hint to the compiler that the function should be inlined. `#[stable]` is used by the standard library to mark APIs that are available on the stable channel. Otherwise, it's really just an empty function! When `_x` goes out of scope as `drop` returns, its destructor is run; there is no other way to perform cleanup tasks implicitly in Rust.

Comment: You don't even have to look at the source. The [documentation for `drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.drop.html) literally has the source code of the function embedded in it.